# What is purpose of FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink?

Tags: sqlite, delphi

When use FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink in SQLite? Is it necessary and how set up in delphi.

My Sqlite work without FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, I needed that for certain advanced features in some other SQLite components.

**Security (TFDSQLiteSecurity)**.  The class allowing you to manage a SQLite database encryption/passwords.  It requires you use FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink.

**Database Validation (TFDSQLiteValidate)**.  This component allows you to access the SQLite Validation Service to perform Sweep, Vacuum, for example.  It requires you to use FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink.

**Backup (TFDSQLiteBackup)**.  This component allows you to perform database backup/restore/copy operations.  It requires you to use FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink.

As for setting it up, I did nothing other than add the component to my project and then point the other components mentioned above to it.  I left DriverID blank.

Comment: ISTR that you need a driver link if you want to SaveToStream/LoadFromStream.